# Xamarin forms: Word doc is not opening in ios app

Tags: pdf, xamarin.forms, webview, ms-word

I am using `Device.OpenUri(new Uri(word_doc_url));` for opening word/pdf doc in my application. Pdf docs are opening fine but word docs are not opening in ios devices. Showing `AccessdeniedAccess` message when open word doc on iPhone.

**Screenshot**

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I have added the `NSAppTransportSecurity` key on my info.plist.

**Screenshot**

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Also tried the webview feature for opening word doc in the app as per [this thread][3].

**PdfWebView.cs in PCL**

```
public class PdfWebView : WebView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty UriProperty = BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: "Uri",
    returnType: typeof(string),
    declaringType: typeof(PdfWebView),
    defaultValue: default(string));
    public string Uri
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(UriProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UriProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

**PdfWebViewRenderer.cs**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(PdfWebView), typeof(PdfWebViewRenderer))]
namespace Projectname.iOS.Renderer
{
    class PdfWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<PdfWebView, UIWebView>
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<PdfWebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                SetNativeControl(new UIWebView());
            }
            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                // Cleanup
            }
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var customWebView = Element as PdfWebView;
                string fileName = Path.Combine(NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, string.Format("Content/{0}", WebUtility.UrlEncode(customWebView.Uri)));
                Control.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(fileName, false)));
                Control.ScalesPageToFit = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In XAML and XAML.cs:

```
<local:PdfWebView 
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    x:Name="pdf_Webview"/>

pdf_Webview.Source = pdfurl;
pdf_Webview.Uri = pdfurl;
```

But pdf and word files are not showing in webview.

Comment: You could use `QLPreviewController` to open the local  word file in your application .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Word file not saved locally.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the library **QuickLook** to preview file inline or from local

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using QuickLook;
//...[assembly]
namespace xxx.iOS
{

    public class PreviewItem : QLPreviewItem
    {
       
        NSUrl fileUrl;

        public override string ItemTitle
        {
            get { return fileUrl.LastPathComponent; }
        }

        public override NSUrl ItemUrl
        {
            get { return fileUrl; }
        }

        public PreviewItem(string filePath)
        {
            fileUrl = NSUrl.FromString(filePath);

          
        }
    }

    class MyWebViewRenderer:ViewRenderer<PdfWebView, UIWebView>,IQLPreviewControllerDataSource,IQLPreviewControllerDelegate
    {
        string filePath;

        public IQLPreviewItem GetPreviewItem(QLPreviewController controller, nint index)
        {
            return new PreviewItem(filePath);
        }

        public nint PreviewItemCount(QLPreviewController controller)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        [Export("previewController:shouldOpenURL:forPreviewItem:")]
        public bool ShouldOpenUrl(QLPreviewController controller,NSUrl url, QLPreviewItem item)
        {
            return true;
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<PdfWebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                SetNativeControl(new UIWebView());
            }
            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                // Cleanup
            }
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var customWebView = Element as PdfWebView;
                filePath = Path.Combine(NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, string.Format("Content/{0}", WebUtility.UrlEncode(customWebView.Uri)));

                var previewController = new QLPreviewController();
               

                previewController.WeakDelegate = this;
                previewController.DataSource = this;

                previewController.CurrentPreviewItemIndex = 0;

                var currentViewController = topViewControllerWithRootViewController(UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.GetWindow().RootViewController);
                currentViewController.PresentViewController(previewController, true, null);
            }
        }




        UIViewController topViewControllerWithRootViewController(UIViewController rootViewController)
        {
            if (rootViewController is UITabBarController)
            {
                UITabBarController tabBarController = (UITabBarController)rootViewController;
                return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(tabBarController.SelectedViewController);
            }
            else if (rootViewController is UINavigationController)
            {
                UINavigationController navigationController = (UINavigationController)rootViewController;
                return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(navigationController.VisibleViewController);
            }
            else if (rootViewController.PresentedViewController != null)
            {
                UIViewController presentedViewController = rootViewController.PresentedViewController;
                return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(presentedViewController);
            }
            else
            {
                return rootViewController;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

You would better open use the `QLPreviewController` directly on the ContentPage in iOS instead of add a webview (use a page renderer).

### Option 2

You could add the Microsoft Office Preview prefix

```
Device.OpenUri(new Uri("https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=your 
 file url"));
```

It works fine on  my side . Your url seems will download the file directly , so make sure the url is accessible.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample project?

Comment: You could provide yours so that I can improve it on my side .

Comment: Ok I will provide a sample first.

Comment: Don't forget to remove your personal info .

Comment: Created a sample project, could you please have a look.https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_f3s6dXXQRfuKyivxXC4U7oQxrCORK52

Comment: It seems that the url of doc is illegal, try to remove the char like (1) (1) .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210733/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-sreejith-sree).

Comment: Did you try to change another url ?

Comment: Any better solution?